# Why must local variables have initial values?

Tags: c#

Why must I initialize variables inside methods?

```
int test1; // Not initialized, but OK

public int Foo()
{
   int test2;                 // Not initialized

   int test3 = test1;         // OK
   int test4 = test2;         // An error
}
```

Comment: That is *only* required if they are actually referenced (used)(?). Then it only results in a warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fields are automatically initialized to the logical zero for the type; this is implicit. Variables must obey "definite assignment", so **must** be assigned before they can be read.

ECMA 334v4

> §17.4.4 Field initialization
>
> The initial value of a field, whether
>   it be a static field or an instance
>   field, is the default value (§12.2) of
>   the field’s type. It is not possible
>   to observe the value of a field before
>   this default initialization has
>   occurred, and a field is thus never
>   "uninitialized".

and

> §12. Variables
>
> ...
>   A variable shall be definitely assigned (§12.3) before its
>   value can be obtained.
>   ...

Comment: That's just repeating the question. But why?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt that depends on whether by "why?" one means the rule or the reason behind the rule. I answered the first, which arguably answers the question; for the second: because by the time you've considered constructor chaining, virtual methods being called during construction, and the fact that at the IL level base constructors can be called at any point in the call chain - it becomes almost impossible to say anything sensible about field initialization; equally, fields can be overlapped making it even more important to zero the space, so no init is technically required - contrast...

Comment: @YairHalberstadt local variables, which have very easy assignment checking, where uninitialized usually means an error, and where we can skip zeroing (although the current runtime never does, IIRC).

Answer (score 13):

Extending Mark's answer, local variable initialization is also related to the **verification process**.

The CLI requires that in any verifiable code (that is, modules that didn't explicitly asked to skip the verification process using the SkipVerfication property from the [SecurityPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securitypermissionattribute%28VS.80%29.aspx) attribute), all local variables must be initialized before their usage. Failing to do so will result in a [VerficationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.verificationexception.aspx) being thrown.

More interestingly, is that the compiler automatically adds the `.locals init` flag on every method that uses local variables. This flag causes the JIT compiler to generate code that initializes all of the local variables to their default values. Meaning, even though you have already initialized them in your own code, the JIT will comply with the `.locals init` flag and generate the proper initialization code. This "duplicate initialization" doesn't effect performance since in configurations that allow optimizations, the JIT compiler will detect the duplication and effectively treat it as "dead code" (the auto-generated initialization routine will not appear in the generated assembler instructions).

According to Microsoft (also, backed up by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) in response to a question on his blog), on most occasions, when programmers don't initialize their local variable, they don't do so because they rely on the underlying environment to initialize their variable to their default values, but only because they "forgot", thus, causing sometimes-illusive logical bugs.

So in order to reduce the probability for bugs of this nature to appear in C# code, the compiler still insists you will initialize your local variables. Even though it's going to add the `.locals init` flag to the generated [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code.

A more comprehensive explanation on this subject can be found here: [Behind The .locals init Flag](http://www.liranchen.com/2010/07/behind-locals-init-flag.html)

Comment: In the blog post ([homonyms](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-There,-Their-and-They%27re)): *"they're default values"* → *"their default values"*, *"before they're usage"* → *"before their usage"*, and *"initialize they're local variables"* → *"initialize their local variables"*. And *"there's several reason"* → *"there are several reasons"* (several changes), *"the compilers constraint"* → *"the compiler's constraint"* (possessive), and *"if the the"* → *"if the"* (repeated word).

Answer (score 4):

It actually shouldn't.  Your error should be on the second line, not the first, and should be because you *used it* before you initialized it.

The compiler is helping you here.

So don't initialize them as a habit. Instead let the compiler help you out!

The nice thing about this is that it will path check for you.  If you have a switch statement with three cases where each sets the value, but you forget to set it in your "default", but use it afterwards, it will warn you that you missed a path.

If you initialize variables to `= 0`, you take that benefit away.

Comment: I also used test1 before I initialized it, but that was ok

Comment: Yes, the same checking isn't helpful with class variables--there is no way to path trace those unless you make them final, then it should assure that they are filled in in the constructor (a good idea where possible)

Answer (score 2):

As Marc indicates, that's what the specification says. The reason this is a *good thing* is that there are some valid reasons to leave a member uninitialized rather than a local variable, whose lifetime is bounded by the method it is in. Mostly you'd only ever want this for performance reasons, if the variable is expensive to initialize, and should only be initialized under specific usage scenarios. For my part, I'd avoid uninitialized members until my back was truly against the wall, though!

For local variables, it is also much easier to detect whether all code paths are likely to lead to initialization, whereas there are no good heuristics to determine whether all code paths across the entire programme guarantee initialization before use. A completely correct answer is [impossible in both cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), as all computer science students should know.