# Variable initializing (C# and C++)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, variables, initialization

Quick question, is it good practice to initialize all "blank or empty" variables when it has not to carry either positive or negative values, for example using this:

```
int value = 0;
```

instead of:

```
int value;
```

I accept the Visual Studio compiler, from what I understand, automatically initializes variables to 0 by default if they are not initialized before hand but I am curious as to what the best practice is and what the potential hazards (if any) are.

Although I am referring to the C# and C++ languages within the VS environment particularly, this question is open to any languages and compilers across the spectrum.

Comment: Let's just stick with c++ and C#, shall we?

Comment: The C++ way is to **always** initialize variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always good practice to initialize variables to prevent undefined behavior later in the program. Some later compilers might do this for you, but at the lower lever not defining a variable CANNOT be caught by the compiler and can lead to some very painful headaches. If you have a massive list of variable i usually use a big equals statement:

```
int a,b,c,d,g;
a=b=c=d=g=0; //set all to zero
```

it's apart of the bigger c++ philosophy to always have a value stored in your variable at **all** times .

Answer (score 7):

> the Visual Studio compiler, from what I understand, automatically initializes variables to 0 by default if they are not initialized before hand

Not always.

Scope matters.  Private members of the class are automatically assigned their default values, but locally-scoped variables (i.e. declared in a method) are not.  `out` parameters are not automatically assigned.  Value and Reference parameters are always assigned (they either get passed in a value, or a default value is declared).

C# will let you assign a value *after* the declaration, but will *not* allow you to reference variables that are not assigned.

Comment: So anything within the local scope must be intialized. What happens with global variables as they are outwith the scope?

Comment: In C#, variables are always declared *within a class.*  C# doesn't have global variables.

Comment: In C++, primitive type data members **will not** be zero initialized. Access doesn't come into it. This includes pointers. It is very important to bear this in mind.

Comment: For C#, there's a good discussion at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515829/non-initialized-variable-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Initialization statements as `int value = 0;` are more preferable and **good programming practice** for two reasons.

1. Its better from readability perspective
2. It removes the possibility of issues due to uninitialized variables(not in this case but a practice to avoid issues in many other cases where initialization is required).