# Why the C# compiler forces explicit initialization of all value type's fields in the constructor?

Tags: c#, struct

For a class, this is OK:

```
class Point
{
    private int _x, _y;

    public Point(int x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }
}
```

But if I use a value type the compiler complains that the `_y` is not initialized:

```
struct Point
{
    private int _x, _y;

    public Point(int x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what's the *rationale* behind this? Why can't the compiler just initialize `_y` to `0` as it does when there is no explicit constructor is provided?

Comment: You probably haven't thought long enough about the *other* ways that the CLR can create that struct, having values you did not count on.  Every struct type has a default constructor, they have to.  Get somewhere by making that constructor private, exposing only a static factory method.  And initialize *all* members to encourage the compiler that you are doing it correctly.  It can only help a little bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why? Because the language specifiaction (ECMA 334 16.4.9) says so:

> No instance function member (including the set accessors for the properties X and Y) can be called until all fields of the struct being constructed have been definitely assigned. Note, however, that if Point were a class instead of a struct, the instance constructor implementation would be permitted.

As for why the language specification demands it... presumably to make struct assignment as cheap as possible by avoiding an unnecessary wipe and overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, now all value types are initialized:

```
struct Point
{
    private int _x, _y;

    public Point(int x)
        :this()
    {
        _x = x;
    }
}
```

Note, I simply called the default constuctor.

I think the reason for this behavior is, that if you either call the default constructor or specify all fields in your constructor with parameters, it shows, you know what you're doing and not accidental initialize some fields to default.

Answer (score 0):

This can be found in Section 5.3.1 of C# spec which states that the following types of variables are initially assigned. The list for the purposes is:

- **Instance variables of class instances.**
- Instance variables of initially assigned struct variables.
- Array elements.
- Value parameters.
- Reference parameters.
- Variables declared in a catch clause or a foreach statement.

The following will give you a value of 0:

```
Point p = new Point(10);
Console.WriteLine(p.y);
```

As the variables are initialized to their default values which can lead to bugs in code, the compiler warns on uninitialised variables.

This by itself won't compile:

```
int temp;
Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

Jon Skeet has a good answer here:

[Non initialized variable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515829/non-initialized-variable-in-c-sharp)