# Why does String.IsNullOrEmpty does not compile whereas I did assign my var

Tags: c#

Update : my question wasn't correctly formulated

When I want to test a variable with `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, Visual Studio complains it is unassigned whereas I did assign it see code below ?

```
String IniFileExtension;


if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(fileDirectory, iniFileName)))
{

    // read ini file
    IniFile iniFile = new IniFile(Path.Combine(fileDirectory, iniFileName));
    string outputFileName= iniFile.IniReadValue("Params","outputFile");
    IniFileExtension= iniFile.IniReadValue("Params","fileExtension");
}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyString)) {}
```

Comment: Why not just initialize it with null and then test if it is still null after you assign the path to the variable?

Comment: More importantly, the above code won't even compile.

Comment: @rbm The OP is asking why "Visual Studio complains" [with a compiler error and doesn't compile].

Comment: Agreed, what i meant to say is that compiler error "Use of unassigned local variable" is pretty clear; i.e. there should not be a way do to so.

Comment: I think what you're missing is the fact that *null* is different to *unassigned*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't C# default to null for unassigned local variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470277/why-doesnt-c-sharp-default-to-null-for-unassigned-local-variables)

Comment: The IsNullOrEmpty is just like other methods in. Net. No special treatment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because a value has not been [definitely assigned](http://www.dotnetperls.com/definite-assignment-analysis) to the local variable; and thus the local variable *cannot* be used in *any* expression<sup>1</sup>.

It has naught to do with `IsNullOrEmpty` and can be reproduced in a number of forms:

```
string x;
string y = "Hello " + x; // <- invalid, x is not definitely assigned.
bool z = null == x;      // <- invalid, x is not definitely assigned.
"Hello".Equals(x);       // <- invalid, x is not definitely assigned.
```

See [Are C# uninitalized variables dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931226/are-c-sharp-uninitalized-variables-dangerous?lq=1) for details about why this is required. Most of the related questions are about a specific form of assignment analysis; but here it was trivially never assigned.

As such - because the code doesn't compile - it is a 'useless' construct as shown.

---

<sup>1</sup> Digression: it can still be used as an `out` parameter.

Comment: @user310291 It will still fail to compile for the same reason. The code added still fails to assign (much less definitely assign) a value to the MyString variable. Even if it was assigned in the 'if' it would still not be definitely assigned - e.g. condition may have been false. The compiler must be able to prove the assignment before use, when runtime information is not available. (The rules for definite assignment are simplistic local branch  analysis.)

Comment: @user310291 The question link I added to the answer has many related questions to specific analysis cases relating to definite assignment.

Comment: user2864740 I am surprised that the compiler would analyze the if. But OK thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the method is very much correct and is working as expected.

It can be the case that your variable is assigned a value and in the due course it becomes `null`.

For e.g.

```
String MyString = "Some String";

//In due course MyString becomes null

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyString)) {}
```