# Why doesn't C# compiler optimize away duplicate local variable default value initialization?

Tags: c#, clr, il

#### Background

I know that Compiler would "Omit generating code for things like `int foo = 0;` for fields Because the memory allocator will initialize fields to default values." [Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx)

```
        class Foo
        {
            public int a = 1;
            public int b = 0;
        }
        Foo..ctor:
        IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
        IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
        IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+Foo.a // There is no b.
        IL_0007:  ldarg.0
        IL_0008:  call        System.Object..ctor
        IL_000D:  ret
```

I also know that "The compiler automatically adds `.locals init` on every method that uses local variables, indicating JIT must inject the code initializing all local variables before commencing the method execution." [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753438/why-must-local-variables-have-initial-values)

#### Question

Why doesn't compiler omit generating IL for things like `int foo = 0;` for local variables since `.locals init` already cover that? (for consistency with fields?)

(I understand C# spec requires local variable to be definitely assigned, I am ok with that.)

(The link I referenced says the reason why `.locals init` is needed, and why C# spec requires locals to be initialized. But it doesn't say why additional IL instructions to initialize the default values must exist. As the verification process is assured by `.locals init` already)

```
void Main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 0;
    int d = a + b + c;
    d++;
}

.maxstack 2
.locals init (int a, int b, int c, int d)

IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // a (Can be optimized away)
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0003:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0005:  stloc.2     // c (Can be optimized away)
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_0008:  add         
IL_0009:  ldloc.2     // c
IL_000A:  add         
IL_000B:  stloc.3     // d
IL_000C:  ldloc.3     // d
IL_000D:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_000E:  add         
IL_000F:  stloc.3     // d
```

Comment: Does `.locals init` cover this case? Those are member variables not local variables, and thus are handled differently?

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now that you clarified the example.

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/a/3383168/56778 answers the question.

Comment: If I were to guess I'd say it has to do with the carbon footprint of the variable, it will be gc'd anyway when the method has finished executing, the class must use idisposable

Comment: @JimMischel I don't think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753438/why-must-local-variables-have-initial-values/3383168#3383168 answers. It says the reason why `.locals init` is essential, and why C# spec requires locals to be initialized. But it doesn't say why additional IL instructions must exist. (as the verification process is assured by `.locals init`)

Comment: I have always wondered why valuetypes must be assigned before use. I prefer C/C++ semantics here.

Comment: End of the second paragraph: *This "duplicate initialization" doesn't effect performance since in configurations that allow optimizations, the JIT compiler will detect the duplication and effectively treat it as "dead code" (the auto-generated initialization routine will not appear in the generated assembler instructions).* As the next paragraph states, the compiler insists on explicit initialization because failure to explicitly initialize local variables is a very common source of bugs.

Comment: @leppie This doesn't have much to do with value types. All local variables have to be assigned and all fields don't have to, no matter what their type is.

Comment: @JimMischel Re your last sentence: That's the reason why the compiler insists on explicit initialization *in C# code*, but it doesn't explain why is the explicit initialization kept *in IL*. What you said before pretty much does explain that, but that has nothing to do with bugs.

Comment: @JimMischel I understand there is no performance difference in local variable cases. But there is no difference in field cases as well. And they do optimize on fields, why not do the same on variables?

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't compiler omit generating IL for things like `int foo = 0;` for local variables since `.locals init` already cover that?

Why should it? I have not actually verified this, but I would be surprised if the JIT compiler generated different native code if you removed the unnecessary initialization.

What this means is that the only benefit adding this optimization to the C# compiler would have is to make the JIT compilation tiny bit faster (because it would have to process smaller amount of IL code). It seems the authors of the C# compiler though that making this optimization for such a tiny benefit is not worth it.

Comment: I understand there is no performance difference in local variable cases. But there is no difference in field cases as well. And they do optimize on fields, why not do the same on variables?

Comment: @colinfang I think “generating consistent IL” is extremely low on the list of priorities for the C# team.

Comment: It might want to do this to optimize IL size and to reduce time spent in JIT. It probably was not high enough on the list though.